# Defining \@ifnextchar to detect a newline

Tags: lists, paragraphs

At the end of a list (eg in `\enditemize` or similar) I need to detect if there is a blank line before whatever comes afterwards. Can this be done by `\@ifnextchar` or has someone already done this somewhere?

Comment: The standard latex list environments already detect this and act differently depending on whether or not they are followed by a blank line (or `\par`)

Comment: Could you extend your question here in light of what @DavidCarlisle says? We probably need more context to give a good answer.